# <ion-tab> not working ionic framework

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, tabs, ionic-framework

Im using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition for building Cordova app. Im also using ionic framework for front end. Im new to Ionic framework. When I use `<ion-tab>` in my home.html file, the output is not showing tab...Here is my code..Thanks in advance

Here's my includes in head tag

```
<script src="scripts/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
```

Here's my code in body tag

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
    <button id="upload-button" class="button icon ion-upload" onclick="window.location.href='test.html'"></button>
    <h1 class="h1 title">Outdoor App</h1>
    <button id="refresh-button" class="button icon ion-refresh" onclick="window.location.reload()"></button>


</div>
<div class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
    <button id="upload-button" class="button icon ion-upload" onclick="window.location.href='test.html'"></button>
    <h1 class="h1 title">Outdoor App</h1>
<button id="refresh-button" class="button icon ion-refresh" onclick="window.location.reload()">
</button>
</div>
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">

<ion-tab title="Home" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">

</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="About" icon-on="ion-ios-clock" icon-off="ion-ios-clock-outline">

</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="Settings" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline">

</ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>

 <script src="scripts/home.js"></script>
```

The `<ion-tab>` tag is not working in ripple emulator as well as in device.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an alternative then the below mentioned code will work in place of those .

```
<ion-tabs>
<a class="tab-item">Home</a>
<a class="tab-item">About</a>
<a class="tab-item">Settings</a>
</ion-tabs>
```